# What is a <selector> element?

Tags: java, android

I read the android manual to learn more about drawable and this is what I have came across. Stated in the android Developer:

item
Defines a drawable to use during certain states, as described by its attributes. Must be a child of a selector element.

1) I am confused about what a selector element is.

2) why do I have to include my item inside the selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selector is the "container" element.

Take for example this `playbutton.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/pause" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_checked="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/play" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pause" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

*(stolen from [here](https://github.com/milkbikis/DownloadAccelerator/blob/master/res/drawable-hdpi/playbutton.xml))*

It's a single button image that dynamically shows different images depending on whether it is currently pressed or not. The system can "select" the item from a list of items and so it was named selector, I guess.

Or "state list" like in the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: Thanks that was the answer I am looking for but one last thing. I just want to confirm to make sure so a selector is basically a container which allows the systems to select the different item correct?

Comment: @Wowzer Yes, you give the system a list of images to pick from, it's going to select the right one. XML syntax needs rules like java too, so instead of `class { ... }` it's in this case `<selector> ...</selector>`. https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Drawables are some more nice examples for xml drawables.